# Azure Lake to Lake transfer of files

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-lake, data-lake

My company has two Azure environments. The first one was a temporary environment and is being re-purposed / decommissioned / I'm not sure. All I know is I need to get files from one Data Lake on one environment, to a DataLake on another. I've looked at adlcopy and azcopy and neither seem like they will do what I need done. Has anyone encountered this before and if so, what did you use to solve it?

Comment: azcopy has the capability copying the content, what challenge did you encounter, or why did you think it was not what you wanted?

Comment: The only capability that AzCopy has if from Blob to Blob, I'm looking for Lake to Lake. In the interest of time, we're creating a factory to copy from Lake to Blob, then Blob to Blob then Blob to Lake. These are on completely different Azure instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can think about [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction), it can helps you transfer files or data from one Azure Data Lake to Another Data Lake.

You can reference [Copy data to or from Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage).

This article outlines how to use Copy Activity in Azure Data Factory to copy data to and from Data Lake Storage Gen2. It builds on the Copy Activity overview article that presents a general overview of Copy Activity.

For example, you can learn from this tutorial: [Quickstart: Use the Copy Data tool to copy data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-copy-data-tool).

In this quickstart, you use the Azure portal to create a data factory. Then, you use the Copy Data tool to create a pipeline that copies data from a folder in Azure Blob storage to another folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for these resources. We still weren't able to find anything to directly copy from one lake within one Azure instance to a completely separate Azure instance. Instead we're doing a data factory pipeline to copy lake to blob, then use AzCopy from Blob to Blob then we'll create another pipeline to copy Blob to Lake. :)